# Centre figures within div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to centre some figures. At the moment the figure's are in two columns, I would like them within three. But every time I attempt to increase the width all the figures go funny, or move slightly to the left. Any help would be kindly appreciated. Visual aid as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/QcLLC/

HTML:

```
        <section class="main">

            <div class="grid clearfix masonry" id="grid" style="position: relative; height: 1820px;">
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/4.jpg"><figcaption style="position: absolute; width: 100%;"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMT">Fall 7 Times Stand Up 8</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/7.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fLBG">Unashamed Optimism of Ambition</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 260px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/1.jpg"><figcaption style="position: absolute; width: 100%;"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMM">Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 650px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/3.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fWPV">Wild Hearts Cannot Be Tamed</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 910px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/5.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fGhI">2012 Detroit Tigers</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 910px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/6.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fKCf">Bad Hair Day</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 1170px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/2.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fQdt">Work Hard. Stay Humble.</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 1170px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/8.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fPEY">Everyone Deserves To Be Adored</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 1430px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/9.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fWwG">Sarah William's Quote</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
            </div>

        </section>

    </div><!-- /container -->
```

CSS:

```
            .grid {
                margin: 30px auto;
            }

            .grid figure {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: 0 1% 10px 1%;
                cursor: pointer;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .grid figure img {
                display: block;
            }

            .grid figure figcaption {
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 400;
                left: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
                bottom: -60px;
                padding: 20px;
                color: #ddd;
                background: #18bcbc;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -webkit-transition: bottom 0.2s ease;
                -moz-transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
                transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
            }

            .grid figure figcaption a {
                color: #fff;
            }

            .grid figure figcaption a:hover {
                color: #ffd468;
            }

            .grid figure:hover figcaption {
                bottom: 0px;
            }





            html { height: 100%; }

            *,
            *:after,
            *:before {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .clearfix:before,
            .clearfix:after {
                content: " ";
                display: table;
            }

            .clearfix:after {
                clear: both;
            }

            .clearfix {
                *zoom: 1;
            }

            body {

                background: #ffe19a url(../images/noisebg.png);
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #333;
                overflow: scroll;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            a {
                color: #555;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .container {
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }

            .main,
            .container {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1275px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
                padding: 0 0 5px 0px
            }
```

Comment: Are there always 2 `<figure>` on each row?

Comment: Yes there is @Mooseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how you could alter the absolute positioning to make a 3 grid layout. http://jsfiddle.net/JDq6C/3/

```
<style>
  .grid {
                margin: 30px auto;
            }

            .grid figure {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: 0 1% 10px 1%;
                cursor: pointer;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .grid figure img {
                display: block;
            }

            .grid figure figcaption {
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 400;
                left: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
                bottom: -60px;
                padding: 20px;
                color: #ddd;
                background: #18bcbc;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -webkit-transition: bottom 0.2s ease;
                -moz-transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
                transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
            }

            .grid figure figcaption a {
                color: #fff;
            }

            .grid figure figcaption a:hover {
                color: #ffd468;
            }

            .grid figure:hover figcaption {
                bottom: 0px;
            }





            html { height: 100%; }

            *,
            *:after,
            *:before {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .clearfix:before,
            .clearfix:after {
                content: " ";
                display: table;
            }

            .clearfix:after {
                clear: both;
            }

            .clearfix {
                *zoom: 1;
            }

            body {

                background: #ffe19a url(../images/noisebg.png);
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #333;
                overflow: scroll;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            a {
                color: #555;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .container {
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }

            .main,
            .container {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1275px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
                padding: 0 0 5px 0px
            }
</style>

<section class="main">

            <div class="grid clearfix masonry" id="grid" style="position: relative; height: 1820px;width: 1240px;">
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/4.jpg"><figcaption style="position: absolute; width: 100%;"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMT">Fall 7 Times Stand Up 8</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/7.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fLBG">Unashamed Optimism of Ambition</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 831px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/1.jpg"><figcaption style="position: absolute; width: 100%;"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMM">Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 266px; left: 413.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/3.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fWPV">Wild Hearts Cannot Be Tamed</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 654px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/5.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fGhI">2012 Detroit Tigers</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 531px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/6.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fKCf">Bad Hair Day</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 655px; left: 831px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/2.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fQdt">Work Hard. Stay Humble.</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 794px; left: 416.34375px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/8.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fPEY">Everyone Deserves To Be Adored</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
                <figure style="position: absolute; top: 917px; left: 0px;" class="masonry-brick"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/9.jpg"><figcaption><a href="http://drbl.in/fWwG">Sarah William's Quote</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption></figure>
            </div>

        </section>

    <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I grasp the situation fully. The inline styles of the `<figure>` tags contradict the CSS rules for them, as it makes no sense floating absolutely positioned elements left.

See a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/kDCM6/ where all the inline styles are removed and the `<figure>`s been given a width to produce a three column layout. The images within have also been given `max-height: 100%` so that they automatically scale with their parent `<figure>`.

Granted, this fiddle does have the nice layout of your original design, but to achieve that, you'd have to look into how those absolute left and top offsets were generated in the first place and change that to a three column layout.

Edit: it appears you are using Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com). If so, you can specify a columnWidth when invoking Masonry. It seems you can automatically specify the column width as a fraction of the container's width like so:

```
$('#container').masonry({
  // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
  columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
    return containerWidth / 3;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify a width for `.grid`: I used `width: 820px`, which can be adjusted according to the content. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QcLLC/1/

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've achieved the desired effect using CSS3 columns and a fixed width on your `section.main`.

I intentionally avoided absolute positioning and moved all the styles into a stylesheet.  I also rearranged your figures to match the order they were in visually on your fiddle.

I didn't even look at the CSS you provided.  It was a little confusing and I was focused on getting you a clean 3-column layout.

I created an example at CodePen, but I used the "Prefix free" option, so you'll either have to work out the vendor prefixes yourself or also use [Prefix free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)

http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/vbFGt

One thing to note is that I had to fix the width of the section and the width of the figures in order to prevent it from cropping the images.

#### HTML

```
<section class="main">
  <div class="grid clearfix masonry" id="grid">
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/4.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fWMT">Fall 7 Times Stand Up 8</a> by Erika Mackley</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/3.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fWPV">Wild Hearts Cannot Be Tamed</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/5.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fGhI">2012 Detroit Tigers</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/2.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fQdt">Work Hard. Stay Humble.</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/9.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fWwG">Sarah William's Quote</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/7.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fLBG">Unashamed Optimism of Ambition</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/1.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fWMM">Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/6.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fKCf">Bad Hair Day</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="masonry-brick">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/StickyCaptionsConcept/images/8.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fPEY">Everyone Deserves To Be Adored</a> by Erika Mackley
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

figure img {
  width: 20em;
}

section.main {
  column-count: 3;
  padding: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  width: 66em;
}
figure:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

figure:nth-of-type(0n+4) {
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```